# How to have multiple values for a key in cypher query for neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I am working with a program that i have a record for every user. My users have a property with key, `PhoneNumber` , and its value is an array of strings, `[454457,897356]`. For example if i wanted to use cypher query:

```
Start n=node(1)
Return n
```

It returns 1 record for my node(one row) that the value of column `PhoneNumber` is an array.
But i want to have record numbers according to the number of values in my array, means that for my example, the query returns 2 records(2 rows) and all of its attributes be the same but in the `PhoneNumber` column one of them has the value `454457` and the other has the value `897356`. Is any way to do that? do i change my cypher query or make some changes in my java code?
Thanks.

Comment: You can do it on the client side when reading the results, just duplicate the original row (user) for each phone # in the record.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that yet, within Cypher. I've submitted a request for it, though:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/30

Comment: can't it be done with foreach? `FOREACH (x in n.PhoneNumber : ...` but i can't figure out the second part.

Comment: The problem is there's no way to expand the results beyond the rows you have, based on the collection. (AFAIK) I'd love to hear otherwise, though.